# Getting error in Jupyter Notebook when importing opencv after installation: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-3.8, ubuntu-20.04, opencv, python

I have installed python3 in my ubuntu 20.04LTS operating system. I have also installed the Jupyter notebook directly from the snap store. Now I am trying to install OpenCV from jupyter notebook using: `pip install OpenCV-python.`
I have also tried: `!pip install OpenCV-python`

In both the case it says requirement already satisfied. Below is the screenshot:
[image]

Whenever I am trying: `import cv2.`
It gives error:`libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.`
Though I have installed OpenCV through the terminal in python3 and it successfully gets imported in python3 terminal. But not able to import in Jupyter notebook.

Please suggest, how can I resolve this issue and import OpenCV to Jupyter Notebook.

Any link where I can learn and understand how these libraries interact with the operating system when installed through python and Jupyter notebooks will be helpful.
Thanking you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening due to using pre-built CPUs. Install package as headless one.
I had similar issue that got resolved by using below command

`pip install opencv-python--headless`

reference https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python-headless/